# what does the `port` mean in kafka zookeeper path `/brokers/ids/$id`

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I got two kafka listeners with config

```
listeners=PUBLIC_SASL://0.0.0.0:5011,PUBLIC_PLAIN://0.0.0.0:5010
advertised.listeners=PUBLIC_SASL://192.168.181.2:5011,PUBLIC_PLAIN://192.168.181.2:5010
listener.security.protocol.map=PUBLIC_SASL:SASL_PLAINTEXT,PUBLIC_PLAIN:PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=PUBLIC_SASL
```

`5010` is plaintext, `5011` is sasl_plaintext.

After startup, I found this information in zookeeper(/brokers/ids/$id):

```
{
    "listener_security_protocol_map": {
        "PUBLIC_SASL": "SASL_PLAINTEXT", 
        "PUBLIC_PLAIN": "PLAINTEXT"
    }, 
    "endpoints": [
        "PUBLIC_SASL://192.168.181.2:5011", 
        "PUBLIC_PLAIN://192.168.181.2:5010"
    ], 
    "jmx_port": -1, 
    "features": { }, 
    "host": "192.168.181.2", 
    "timestamp": "1658485899402", 
    "port": 5010, 
    "version": 5
}
```

What does the `port` filed mean? Why the port is `5010`? Could I change it to `5011`?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing are `advertised.port` and `advertised.host` Kafka settings, which may be parsed from the `advertised.listener` list for backward compatibility, but both of these are deprecated, however, and the Kafka protocol now uses the protocol map and corresponding `endpoints` list, instead.